# error build: failed to read asset tags: The command xxx exited with status 1

Tags: xcode

I have this error:

error build: failed to read asset tags: The command `(cd /Users/anais/Downloads/Cronometraje && /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/actool --print-asset-tag-combinations --output-format xml1 /Users/anais/Downloads/Cronometraje/Cronometraje/Assets_Pro.xcassets)` exited with status 1. The command's standard output was:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>com.apple.actool.asset-tag-combinations</key>
<array/>
<key>com.apple.actool.errors</key>
<array>
<dict>
<key>debug-description</key>
<string>JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set. around line 1, column 0.</string>
<key>description</key>
<string>The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.</string>
<key>failure-reason</key>
<string>The data is not in the correct format.</string>
</dict>
</array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Somebody can help to me?

I use xcode 14

Many thanks,